# Android Widget post-Install Problem!

Tags: android, eclipse, android-widget, widget, manifest

my widget is full and ready to work, after i install it i can't find in the emulator widgets list .. although it's there when i search for it in the installed applications .. i think it's a problem in the manifest, here is the manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="help.i.bored.bad" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.2">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <!-- Broadcast Receiver that will process AppWidget updates -->
    <receiver android:name=".HitsWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="help.i.bored.bad.HitsWidge.receiver1" />
            <action android:name="help.i.bored.bad.HitsWidge.receiver2" />
            <action android:name="help.i.bored.bad.HitsWidge.receiver3" />

        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/hitswidge_provider" />

    </receiver>

    <Service android:name=".MediaService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="help.i.bored.bad.HitsWidge.receiver2" />
            <action android:name="help.i.bored.bad.HitsWidge.receiver1" />
        </intent-filter>

    </Service>

    <Activity android:name=".Stations" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="help.i.bored.bad.HitsWidge.receiver3" />
        </intent-filter>

    </Activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Broadcast receiver doesn't listen for the android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE action. This is all covered in:

[AppWidgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Comment: still nothing.. i don't really need that action since i'm not using an update period!

Comment: I could be wrong, but isn't the initial we are going to make an appwidget ... an update? Also it might be something with your bindings in the xml file referenced too. Usually logcat will say something when it can't find a component which is declared.